# "Commonly used to select" or "commonly used for selecting"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I read about the prepositions, **for**, and **to**. For example, **to** can be used with times, directions. **for** can be used as **because of**. However, I am still confused about my sentence. I think the first one is correct as my method do something. While the second sentence shows the reasons.

I have a commonly used method, A, which is used to select the best fit model. What one of my sentences is correct? and Why?

> Method A is a commonly used method to select the best fit model.

or

> Method A is a commonly used method for selecting the best fit model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all essential purposes, they mean exactly the same thing and both are fine. It's simply a matter of preference.

---

Personally, I would drop the repetition of *method*.

> Method A is commonly used to select the best fit model.
>   Method A is commonly used for selecting the best fit model.

Only if it's the *most* commonly used method, would I use the word twice (note also how that changes the syntax in both sentences and the preposition in the second):

> Method A is the method most commonly used to select the best fit model.
>   Method A is the most commonly used method of selecting the best fit model.

---

Last, I'm not sure about *best fit model*. The meaning is slightly ambiguous and it seems to me that it should be punctuated or phrased differently:

> the best-fit model
>   the best model fit
>   the model with the best fit

But I'm not sure of the intended meaning, so I don't know which would be better.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I meant the best-fit model. Sometimes we use the best-fitted model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have an additional question; I often prefer the prefix 'in' to 'for', like writing as 'used in selecting' instead of 'used for selecting'. Is this way also acceptable?

Comment: @GwangmuLee Yes, you can use *in* too. I think it's used less often in this particular context, but there's nothing wrong with it. Although I find it sounds a little odd in the version of the sentence where I used *the most*. I'm afraid I can't give a logical reason for that, aside from my own use of the language.

Comment: @JasonBassford Yes, I think getting used to the natural usage through examples is the best bet I can do. Thank you again :)